# Getting audio to start after you click on the play button

Tags: javascript, css

What would I change in the code if I didn't want the audio to start after you clicked on it. If I wanted the play button to show, and not pause, with no audio playing until you clicked on the play button and not the picture?

How it looks now after you **Click** on the image. It goes straight to the audio. I want it to go to the play button first.

https://jsfiddle.net/7ux1s23j/42/

[image]

I want it to go to this image first after you click on the picture.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb7Z0.png)

```html
<style>
  .playButton {
    width: 266px;
    height: 174px;
  }
  
  .initial {
    width: 260px;
    height: 168px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right, transparent, transparent 83px, #0059dd 83px, #0059dd 86px, transparent 86px, transparent 174px, #0059dd 174px, #0059dd 177px, transparent 177px, transparent 260px), url("https://i.imgur.com/BBYxKcf.jpg");
    border: 3px solid #0059dd;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #0059dd;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .playButton.playing {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: -112px 0 0 108px;
    fill: #aaff00;
  }
  
  .links div {
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
  }
  
  .links a {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: -50px 0 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  a.x1 {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  a.x2 {
    margin-left: 54px;
  }
  
  a.x3 {
    margin-left: 108px;
  }
  
  a.x4 {
    margin-left: 162px;
  }
  
  a.x5 {
    margin-left: 216px;
  }
  
  .links a:hover,
  .links a:active,
  .links a:focus {
    background: blue;
  }
  
  .scrl a:visited {
    background: orange;
    color: #000000;
  }
  
  .scrl a:hover {
    background: red;
  }
  
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .links div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

</style>


<div class="myLinkDiv">
  <div class="links">
    <div>
      <a class="x1" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x2" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x3" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x4" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x5" href="" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a class="x1" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x2" href="" target="_blank"></a>

      <a class="x4" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x5" href="" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <a class="x1" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x2" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x3" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x4" href="" target="_blank"></a>
      <a class="x5" href="" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="playButton">

  <div class="initial ">Links</div>

  <svg class="pause" style="display: none;margin:5px 7px;" width="36" height="40" viewbox="0 0 60 100">
    <path d="M0 8c0-5 3-8 8-8s9 3 9 8v84c0 5-4 8-9 8s-8-3-8-8V8zm43 0c0-5 3-8 8-8s8 3 8 8v84c0 5-3 8-8 8s-8-3-8-8V8z"></path>
  </svg>

  <svg class="play hide " style="margin:5px 9px;" width="38" height="40" viewbox="0 0 85 100">
    <path d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>

<audio id="player" preload="none">
  <source src="http://hi5.1980s.fm/;" type="audio/mpeg">
  </source>
</audio>

<script>
  (function iife() {
    "use strict";
    document.querySelector(".myLinkDiv").classList.add("hide");

    function playButtonClickHandler() {
      document.querySelector(".myLinkDiv").classList.remove("hide");
      var button = document.querySelector(".playButton");
      var player = document.querySelector("#player");
      document.querySelector('.playButton .initial').style.display = 'none';
      player.volume = 1.0;
      if (player.paused) {
        button.classList.add("playing");
        document.querySelector(".playButton .play").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".playButton .pause").style.display = "inline-block";
        player.play();
      } else {
        document.querySelector(".playButton .play").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.querySelector(".playButton .pause").style.display = "none";
        player.pause();
      }
    }
    var playButton = document.querySelector(".playButton");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", playButtonClickHandler);
  }());

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

```js
//music
var audio = new Audio('http://www.sousound.com/music/healing/healing_01.mp3')
checksound();



function checksound() {

var myElement = document.getElementById("soundMenu");
  myElement.innerHTML = "Turn Sound " + (audio.paused ? "OFF" : "ON");

  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="soundMenu" onclick="checksound()">Play</button>
```